# calendar initialize in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am using a calendar in my project and after using the information

i want to set it back to default and i am having a trouble with it

Edit :

sorry for any misunderstanding, lets say the user changed the calendar,

how can i set it to the way it was before the user changed it (no marks of dates and back to the previous way it was)

Comment: What kind of problems? We cannot remote debug your program, really)

Comment: i just want to know how is it possible to set the calender item to his default state so the selected date would be just like before the calendar was touched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey i found it:

```
calendar.SelectedDate = null;
calendar.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
```